# CoreBlueTooth compatability with older IOS Devices

Tags: swift, bluetooth

My application transfers text data between iPhones and iPads using CoreBluetooth.

Everything works fine between iphone 10, 11, and 12 and Late Model Ipads.  But will not work  between one of these and an Iphone 6+.  Most of the data gets dropped.

Is there compatability issues with older devices?

thanks,
Rob

When I transfer data between iphone 12 and iphone 6+ the iphone 6 only sees a fraction of the data.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 7 is the first iPhone to support Data Length Extensions (part of Bluetooth 4.2). Prior to iPhone 7, the maximum MTU size was 27 bytes. DLE raises this to 251 bytes. If you're chunking your data into packets larger than 27 bytes (in practice often ~21 bytes of payload), you're likely overwhelming the system, particularly if you're writing without responses. Use [`CBPeripheral.maximumWriteValueLength(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1620312-maximumwritevaluelength) to find the largest value you can send in a single write.

iPhone 8 added Bluetooth 5.0, which is dramatically faster as well, but it should negotiate down to what the iPhone 6+ can handle as long as you don't write values that are larger than allowed.

Note that iPhone 6 does support Bluetooth 4.2, but it doesn't support DLE.

For more details on DLE, see [What's New in Core Bluetooth (2017)](https://web.archive.org/web/20210816230531/https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/712/). It's no longer available from Apple, but should be accessible through archive.org.